# Look up value in an array

Tags: python, sql, scala, databricks

Suppose I have two datasets

```
DS1
ArrayCol
[1,2,3,4]
[1,2,3]

DS2
Key            Name
1              A
2              B
3              C
4              D
```

how to look up the values in the array to map the "Name" so that I can have another dataset like the following?

```
DS3
COlNew
[A,B,C,D]
[A,B,C]
```

Thanks, it's in databricks, so method is ok . python,sql,scala…...

Answer (score 0):

you can try this

```
ds1 = [[1, 2, 3, 4], [1, 2, 3]]
ds2 = {1: 'A', 2: 'B', 3: 'C', 4: 'D'}
new_data = [[ds2[cell] for cell in col] for col in ds1]
print(new_data)
```

output:

```
[['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'], ['A', 'B', 'C']]
```

hope that will be help. :)

Comment: Hi. this is not quite work for me .
"col" is the column name ?

Comment: col means an item in ds1.just like i in "for i in range(10)" statement

Answer (score 0):

Lets consider your dataset are in files and you can do something like this,

making use of `dict`

```
f=open("ds1.txt").readlines()
g=open("ds2.txt").readlines()
u=dict(item.rstrip().split("\t") for item in g)
for i in f:
    i = i.rstrip().strip('][').split(',')
    print [u[col] for col in i]
```

Output

```
['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']
['A', 'B', 'C']
```